# Должен ли я делать commit после каждой транзакции?

Tags: c#, postgresql

По какой-то причине у меня код выпадает с ошибкой:
`System.InvalidOperationException: An operation is already in progress.`

Я немного почитал и пришел к выводу, что проблема может быть в том, что я не завершаю транзакции (не выполняю коммиты). Вопрос вот. В них ли дело, и в какой момент мне их нужно совершать. Нужно ли перед каждым запросом стартовать транзакцию или как?

public void PGConnect()
        {

```
      //  UserData [] uds;
        List<UserData> uds = new List<UserData>();
        UserData ud;

        List<string> dblist = GetListDBsList();
        if (dblist.Contains(config.PGdbName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data Base exists: {0}", config.PGdbName);
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data Base DO NOT exists: {0}", config.PGdbName);
            return;
        }

        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=" + config.PGLogin + ";" +
           "Password=" + config.PGPass + ";Database=" + config.PGdbName + ";");

        //select datname from pg_database;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("PG Connected");
        }

        catch(SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

        }

        //NpgsqlTransaction tr = conn.BeginTransaction();
        // Где-то в этом блоке ошибка 
        string tablesListRequestSQL = @"SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'";
        NpgsqlCommand commandGetDBTables = new NpgsqlCommand(tablesListRequestSQL, conn);
        NpgsqlDataReader drGetDBTables = commandGetDBTables.ExecuteReader();
        //tr.Commit();
        while (drGetDBTables.Read())
        {
            existsInDBTables.Add(drGetDBTables[0].ToString());
        }

        foreach (string table in requireTablesList) // 
        {
            if (!existsInDBTables.Contains(table)) // if element from requireTablesList do not found -> DB have not simmilar Tables!
            {
                notFoundedTables.Add(table);
            }

        }

        if (notFoundedTables.Count != 0) // if not empty
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Next tables are marked as reqired for Sync, but can't be found in DataBase: ");

            foreach (var table in notFoundedTables)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(table);
            }
        }
        // Конец блока где ошибка.


        Console.ReadKey();


         NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT city, state FROM cities", conn);


        try
        {

            NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
               // UserData ud = new UserData();
                ud.id = Int32.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                ud.guid = (dr[1].ToString());
                ud.name = (dr[2].ToString());
                ud.userblob = (byte[])dr[3];
                uds.Add(ud);
                //File.WriteAllBytes("outputimg.jpg", ud.userblob);
                //Console.ReadKey();

            }

        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Тут работает простой принцип - если транзакцию открыли, то нужно ее и закрыть. Другое дело, что транзакция может стартовать автоматом.

C# и подобные языки приучают, что придет GC и все почистит. Но с базами пока так не работает.

Если транзакции не закрывать, то может быть два варианта - либо драйвер все таки закроет за вами (но я сильно сомневаюсь),либо он просто сделает rollback и данные просто потеряются.

Comment: Транзакция - это набор операций в БД, которые либо производятся все вместе, либо не производится ни одна из них.

Comment: Суть транзакции в атомарности изменений. Пример - Ввм нужно модифицировать несколько таблиц. Если все изменения не сделать, то база будет "разсогласована". А приложение может случайно упасть в процессе модификации базы.

Comment: Спасибо, а что у меня в коде может ошибку вызывать? Я пометил блок если закомментировать который все работает.

Comment: делать транцзации на один select запрос как то странно. Транзакции делаются на изменения (insert/update/delete).

Comment: `commit` должен быть как минимум после цикла чтения записей. Когда сделали `commit` все команды, ридеры, открытые в транзакции (после `beginTransaction`) становятся недействительными.

Comment: То есть у меня ошибка из-за того что коммита нет?

Comment: У вас когда ошибка возникает? Когда с коммитом или когда без коммита? вот этот блок `catch(SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

        }` выполняется?

Comment: Когда без. Его пробовал добавить, но если в двух местах, то  ругается, что транзакции не могут быть вложенными.

С блоком try-catch та же самая фигня. Текст ошибки не изменился.

Comment: `99,9%` уверен что даже не устанавливает подключение к базе, а `cath` выводит ошибку в консоль, вы этот вывод тупо не замечаете, далее программа как ни в чем не бывало доходит до первого запроса, но соединения с базой нет, и тут вы замечаете какую-то мессагу с ошибкой. Никакого ни `commit`, ни `beginTransaction` Вам не нужно. А нужно смотреть вот сюда `"Host=myserver;Username=mylogin;Password=mypass;Database=mydatabase"`, смотреть что в Вашем коде, искать 10 различий.

Comment: @Sergey http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/20/5717882d0b968.png
Соединяется же

Comment: Тогда поместите этот блок в `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }` в консоль выведет что-то вроде stacktrace. и будет ясно в какой функции ошибка.

Comment: http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/20/57179041abaa4.png
http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/20/571790825648f.png

Comment: включить в `try` `NpgsqlCommand commandGetDBTables =` И обратите внимание. `WriteLine(e)` а не `WriteLine(e.message)`, можно `WriteLine(e.ToString())`, `WriteLine(e.StackTrace)`,

Comment: Фиг поймёшь где у вас там exception, то он был на первом запросе, теперь на втором показываете. Если первый запрос выполняется, а второй нет, тогда закройте command и reader первого запроса, перед тем, как перейти ко второму.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь не закрыт reader drGetDBTables, поэтому нельзя сделать второй запрос в соединении.

> You should always call the Close method when you have finished using
>   the DataReader object. If your Command contains output parameters or
>   return values, they will not be available until the DataReader is
>   closed.
>   **Note** that while a DataReader is open, **the Connection is in use
>   exclusively by that DataReader**.You cannot execute any commands for the
>   Connection, including creating another DataReader, until the original
>   DataReader is closed.